# True Type Fonts isn't being loaded any more. It seems to be an issue with the End User Agreement

Tags: apt, package-management, fonts

After running

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

I see the text 'Package configuration' followed by a grey box with Configuring `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` in red followed by the end-user license agreement t's & c's and OK at the bottom, but there doesn't seem to be any way to accept it.

That dialogue just seems to sit there, and if I close the terminal it kills the process.

I've had True Type Fonts installed before, but they seem to have broken in the last few weeks.

(I added this to an existing TTF question since it seems to be related, but was asked to raise it separately.)

Edit:
Every time I run the Software Updater, I see this message:
[FailureToDownload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1h8n.png)

I was trying to resolve it by installing via the terminal, but then I ran into the End User Agreement problem.  After that, I couldn't launch the Package Manager because there was a temp file in  /var/lib/dpkg/updates, so I had to run cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates    sudo rm * to get rid of it.

I then ran Software Updater, and saw a popup inviting me to accept the End User Agreement for True Type Fonts.  "Aha!" thought I "Problem now solved!"  So I clicked on the Accept box and on the continue button.  The update finished, but immediately afterwards I saw the Failure to Download message once again.

Groundhog Day!

Answer (score 0):

Sudo apt-get clean actually deletes the package cache. So, you won't be able to reinstall it. You have to use synaptic package manager or apt-get install to install it again.